# Pipe-lining two python programs

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I know the similar questions were posted here but I couldn't get my code working.
I want to pipe one python program output to other's input. The one that is waiting for input has raw_input('>')

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
import subprocess
gen = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'first.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
start = subprocess.Popen(['python','second.py'], stdin=gen.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
start.communicate()
```

first.py:

```
try:
    while(1):
        print gen()
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

The output doesn't produce anything

Any advices?

Comment: This explains the behavior http://bugs.python.org/issue1191964
I am thinking to change my fist.py programm to only returns a single value and second.py to call it each time. 
Could it be done with suboricess?

Comment: I did a hack which gives the right input but not sure if this is a good way to solve the problem
http://pastebin.com/PwUtNpxa
and in t3.py:
http://pastebin.com/K3JdYa13

Comment: I did a hack which gives the right input but not sure if this is a good way to solve the problem
http://pastebin.com/PwUtNpxa
and in t3.py:
http://pastebin.com/K3JdYa13
the only problem is that it's outputting one additional >>

Answer (score 0):

What's your complete second.py like? Even though it should work with raw_input(), did you try reading from sys.stdin? The code snippet you have shown looks fine as it worked for me.

Another possible problem could be that your first.py never reaches completion as the program continues to execute. The second subprocess command will not be executed unless the first one has completed. So try out your first.py without the infinite loop. Make it stop and then try and perhaps your piping will work.

Comment: try:
    while(1):
        word = raw_input('>')
        result = spellchecker(word)
        if result:
            print result
        else:
             print 'NO SUGGESTION'
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)

Comment: Okay so it looks like that you want first.py to be generating some output and you want second.py to consume it as first.py generates some output. And you want it to go forever. Well, to my knowledge this is not possible with pipelining because how pipelining works is the second command is executed only when the first command has been executed completely. In your case, first.py does not reach completion at all. To achieve what you want, the simplest solution would be TCP sockets where one process sends data to the other one and the other one works only when it receives any data.

Comment: This may go on forever as well. This is not the only way of achieving this but there are many other ways of doing this. This is perhaps the simplest way to do it. Another way could be, use another python script (say main.py), which continuously runs first.py and pipelines it with second.py in while loop. The difference would be that you will have to make sure that first.py and second.py must complete there execution.

Comment: is there a better way to solve the problem if my first.py returns only single value and to be called each time second.py needs an input ?

Comment: Well, one way could be that you can have your first.py return only one value every execution. And have your second.py execute first.py using subprocess as many times as you want. Will this solve your problem?

Comment: first.py returns different output each time.
It would be great if I could do something like:
as long as second.py is alive -> call first.py each time.
I am trying to do this but anything I got so far is getting only one input and EOF after with second.py terminating

Comment: i tried this:
start.stdin.write(gen.readline())
stdout, stderr =  start.communicate()